# How do I solve the block puzzle in the Coral Mines?

Tags: shantae-and-the-seven-sirens

There is a block puzzle near the entrance of the Coral Mines with a key-shaped container. The blocks can be rearranged to form [a path to the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MKXZ.jpg), but I can’t figure out what to do next.

How do I solve this block puzzle in the Coral Mines?

[image: coral mines block puzzle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange the blocks to form a path to the container, then climb down the chain in the top-left. Wait for a lava ball to fall from the ceiling, then break the container open for a key.

This type of puzzle appears multiple times, so the solution for each one is shown below.

[image: Block puzzle 1]

[image: Block puzzle 2]

[image: Block puzzle 3]